# Having trouble reading AWS config file with python configparser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, configparser

I ran `aws configure` to set my access key ID and secret access key. Those are now stored in `~/.aws/credentials` which looks like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ######
aws_secret_access_key = #######
```

I'm trying to access those keys for a script I'm writing using configparser. This is my code:

```
import configparser

def main():
    ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
    ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ''

    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

    print (config.read('~/.aws/credentials')) ## []
    print (config.sections())                 ## []
    ACCESS_KEY_ID = config.get('default', 'aws_access_key_id') ##configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'default'
    print(ACCESS_KEY_ID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run the script using `python3 script.py`. Any ideas of what's going on here? Seems like configparser just isn't reading/finding the file at all.

Comment: Are you trying to do this so that you can eventually make API calls to AWS in your Python script? If so, just use Boto3 and it will automatically read the config file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`configparser.read` doesn't try to expand the leading tilde '~' in the path to your home directory.

You can provide a relative or absolute path

```
config.read('/home/me/.aws/credentials')
```

or use [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)<sup>1</sup>

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~/aws/credentials')
config.read(path)
```

or use [pathlib.Path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser)

```
path = pathlib.PosixPath('~/.aws/credentials')
config.read(path.expanduser())
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Improved code from [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1434495/flair)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052089/having-trouble-reading-aws-config-file-with-python-configparser/59052532#comment113843439_59052532).

Comment: You don't need `os.path.join()`. OP can just do `os.path.expanduser('~/.aws/credentials')`

Comment: `Path('~/.aws/credentials').expanduser()` worked for me, not sure if it is a newer version of pathlib/python thing